# Como os representar números complexos em C?

Tags: c, matemática

Como representar um número complexo z = x + yi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seria fazendo a inclusão de [`complex.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main() {
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 2.0;
    double complex z = x + y * I;
    printf("%.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(z), cimag(z));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gCPZ6D). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/poikbihd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Complex.c).